# Quotient ring is infinite dimensional

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is not a principal ideal domain. So I'm looking at the ideal $(x,y)$ and trying to show it is not principal.

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ is 1 dimensional, and I want to show that for any principal ideal, $I$, that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I$ is infinite dimensional but not quite sure how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for the dimension approach: consider the ideal $I = (f)$, and assume without loss of generality that $f \notin \mathbb C[x]$. Show that $1+I, x+I, x^2+I, \cdots$ gives an infinite set of linearly independent coset representatives for $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x$ and $y$ should be of the form $fg$ and $fh$ respectively, where $f$ is the supposed generator. What can you say about degrees?

Comment: Probably should have said this in the question, I am aware I can do it this way because then $f$ would divide $x$ and $y$ so $f$ must be a unit and $<f>$ would be the whole ring which is a contradiction. But I was wondering how to show it by using the dimensions of the quotient rings (as vector spaces) that I mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming that $I$ is a maximal ideal as well?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein No, why?

Comment: "algebraic over $\mathbb C$" sort of presumes that it's in a field extension, doesn't it?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein There's no problem in that, the powers of an element cannot be linearly independent, so any element satisfies a polynomial. However it's not necessarily true that this polynomial can be assumed irreducible, so I'll roll back.